# RichHtmlField not rendering properly inside sharepoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, asp.net-webcontrol

Hey i have a sharepoint page where i let the user use edit mode to edit the content of the page.

This is my Display panel where the content is shown

```
<wss:EditModePanel ID="pnlDisplay" runat="server" PageDisplayMode="Display" SuppressTag="true">
    <wss:RichHtmlField ID="txtTitre" runat="server" FieldName="TitreNouvelle"/>
    <wss:RichHtmlField ID="txtSousTitre" runat="server" FieldName="NouvelleSoustitre" />
    <wss:RichHtmlField ID="txtSommaire" runat="server" FieldName="NouvelleSommaire" />
    <wss:RichHtmlField ID="txtContenu" runat="server" FieldName="NouvelleContenu" />
    <asp:Image ID="imageNouvelle" runat="server" FieldName="NouvelleImgURL"/>
</wss:EditModePanel>
```

This is where the content is edited.

```
<wss:EditModePanel ID="pnlEditPanel" runat="server" PageDisplayMode="Edit" SuppressTag="false">
    <wss:RichHtmlField ID="editTxtTitre" runat="server" FieldName="TitreNouvelle"/>
    <wss:RichHtmlField ID="editTxtSousTitre" runat="server" FieldName="NouvelleSoustitre" />
    <wss:RichHtmlField ID="editTxtSommaire" runat="server" FieldName="NouvelleSommaire" />
    <wss:RichHtmlField ID="editTxtContenu" runat="server" FieldName="NouvelleContenu" />
    <asp:Image ID="EditImgNouvelle" runat="server" FieldName="NouvelleImgURL"/>
</wss:EditModePanel>
```

The problem i have is that when i go into edit mode inside the page, i can edit the content just fine but after saving, if i switch back to display mode it only shows the HTML tags. Title will show the strong html tag before the title, am getting the source of the HTML and not the result. Any help ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Content type where the problem, where they were registered as Text and not HTML which is why they showed HTML tags, i simply went to the list of pages and delete my content type and its columns, when i redeployed it updated the content type to have the correct field type.

You can make sure you have the right field type by coding a small snippet that outputs all the fields from your content type, from web.ContentTypes[index]